# Can anyone help identifying markings on this artillery shell casing?

Tags: identification, england, artillery

Inherited this shell casing from my grandfather who emigrated from England around war time (WW2) but I don't have any real information or dates. My mother just remembers it always being around. My only amateur google sleuthing has figured out its from England and has been re-fired.
Thanks for any help!

Length - 200mm

Diameter of casing at top - 85mm

Diameter of casing at bottom above lip - approx 93mm-95mm

Lip Diameter - 103-105mm (I measure it at 103-104 wondering if it's just lost a 1mm)

[image]

[image]

Comment: omg yep I did the circumference lol thank you! Diameter 105mm

Comment: thanks for your help so far guys, updated the title and post with more info

Comment: By "War time" do you mean WWII?

Comment: yes I believe so

Comment: May be from a 25pdr arty piece although the nominal diameter of that was slightly larger (87mm) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:QF_25_pounder_Ammunition-001.jpg Are your measurements exact?

Comment: I just have a ruler and no caliper so I could be off. I'll recheck and update my post